# Natural language processing (sentiment classification) API for French text

Tags: sens, ressources, lexique

Does anyone know of a good (preferably free or better yet open source) API for natural language processing in French? I have a small dataset (pre-classified into "positive" and "negative" sentiment) on a particular subject, but I'd prefer not to write and train my own classifier algorithm (partly because the classification precision will be mediocre because the dataset is only 5000 phrases or so).

Comment: No certain your algorithm can take care of pronounciation : all words  affective have two opposite meaning : "salaud" from a female in love can be positive, and totally negative when you want to injury somebody - And "bonheur" is not really positive for mystic or oriental thinking, it is not an aim

Comment: I believe Patrick Paroubek has done some work on sentiment analysis, you could contact him for pointers. Also if you feel you don't have enough data, a [student of his](http://lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2010/pdf/385_Paper.pdf) did his PhD thesis on gathering data for sentiment analysis from Twitter based on the occurrence of positive and negative smileys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all the current approaches in sentiment analysis require a lexicon to detect classes (positive/negative or more refined ones). And the big problem is: this lexicon has to be adapted to new corpora, so it's extremely hard to find an existing classifier that will work on your data, because it won't have the correct lexicon to handle it.

You'll certainly have to work a little bit yourself if you want to obtain correct results.

Some ongoing competitions should deliver interesting approaches and resources in a close future: [DEFT 2015](https://deft.limsi.fr/2015/). But it's still a bit early to exploit them.

Comment: Good point about the influence of the lexicon on classifier accuracy. You're right, the topic of the corpus I have is esoteric, so a conventional lexicon would perform poorly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FEEL: a French Expanded Emotion Lexicon.
http://advanse.lirmm.fr/feel.php
It contains more than 14 000 distinct French terms associated with either the conveyed polarity and the expressed emotion(s). It follows the Ekman emotional typology (Ekman, 1992) with 2 polarities and 6 basic emotions classes.

We have learned sentiment classification models on DEFT 2007 and DEFT 2015 benchamrks. We were ranked first, third and fifth on the different benchmarks.
We have made this models online on a dedicated web platform.
http://advanse.lirmm.fr:8081/sentiment-analysis-webpage/index
You just have to upload a file containing french text documents to obtains the expressed sentiments. You may also use the models locally by downloading a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Semantics is a difficult topic in NLP... Stanford has [some great NLP tools](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software) that I suggest you take a look at, though they don't have anything for semantic analysis as far as I can tell.

If this is for a large, ongoing project I implore you to write your own classifier! Though it would take a non-trivial amount of time and effort in the research and development it would be of great benefit to the NLP community!

If you take the above approach, you could use existing word-tagging libraries (Stanford has one for French), combined with something like [Lexique's French lexicon](http://lexique.org/telLexique.php), and add your own semantic entries to the lexicon; then, train a Bayes classifier on your dataset. It's not a perfect approach, but a good start in the right direction!

**Edit** You mention in your question that you don't want to write your own classifier because your dataset isn't large enough. I challenge that statement by telling you that a recent research project at my university trained a Bayes classifier to 75% accuracy to detect sarcasm with only 150 samples!

Comment: stanford does have something for sentiment analysis: http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/index.html it's not state of the art anymore but it's very close.

Comment: @m09 Nice! I didn't see that on their page, that'll be a great source for OP to build off of other existing NLP tools :)

Comment: Point taken on classifier precision. It's not for a large project, so maybe I'll settle for a reduced accuracy rate.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour, Vous pouvez essayer Lettria. Les sentiments sont traite par calcul:
Par exemple: il est tres bon = 1.5
Il est bon = 0.5
il n est pas bon = -0.5
Plus d erreur de faux positifs ou de negation

Comment: Un petit développement serait le bienvenu.